# PHP замена цвета пикселя

Tags: php

Есть обычная картинка png. одноцветная, только у некоторых пикселей разная прозрачность.

Нужно заменить все пиксели на любой другой цвет, сохраняя прозрачность пикселя.

Как это можно сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.

Не могу как определить прозрачность пикселя? нужно на стандартном php

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону imagic

Comment: можно не заменять все пиксели а наложить изображение прозрачного красного квадрата (к примеру) и таким образо тёмный пиксель будет выглядить темнее а светлый светлее, но тон измениться ближе к красному и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

На чистом `PHP` не получится. Необходимый минимум - это стандартное `PHP` расширение [`GD`](http://php.net/manual/ru/intro.image.php). Вполне возможно, что оно у вас уже активировано.

Перво-наперво, вам потребуется создать изображение в памяти `PHP`, для этого предназначены многочисленные функции семейства [`imagecreate*`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php). Например, создаем из png файла:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('путь к файлу.png');
```

Определить цвет и прозрачность пикселя поможет функция [`imagecolorat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) (для удобства можно дополнительно применить и [`imagecolorsforindex`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorsforindex.php)). Из документации:

Результат:

```
array(4) {
  ["red"]=>
  int(119)
  ["green"]=>
  int(123)
  ["blue"]=>
  int(180)
  ["alpha"]=>
  int(127)
}
```

Чтобы установить пиксель на изображении, используется функция [`imagesetpixel`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php), ее сигнатура:

```
bool imagesetpixel ( resource $image , int $x , int $y , int $color )
```

Здесь в ранее созданное изображение в точку с координатами `$x`, `$y` выводится пиксель с цветом `$color`, который дополнительно нужно создать.

Для того чтобы получить цвет с альфа каналом, используется функция [`imagecolorallocatealpha`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php), ее сигнатура:

```
int imagecolorallocatealpha ( resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue , int $alpha )
```

Предлагаю изучить материалы по ссылкам, тогда самостоятельно написать нужный вам скрипт не составит труда.